# Using an https:// asmx-based service with Monotouch

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.ios, asmx, system.net

I'm trying to add a web reference to an asmx web service with ssl. I'm getting this error:
*Error getting response stream:(Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.)SendFailure*
I have self a signed certificate.

Is there a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding this to your code:
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };
If it helps, you have to take care of the certificate checking.

Comment: Are you suggesting I shouldn't add a reference at all?

Answer (score 3):

It's a trust issue. Your application depends on Mono and the iOS certificate stores to deice if an TLS/SSL connection is acceptable. By default self-signed certificates are not (because they are unknown to both Mono and iOS).

Like mentioned in the comments, using System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback is likely the easiest solution - but blindly returning true is not :-)

There's a wiki article on the Mono-project web site that describe several options:
http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully